# Problem with onclick="function()" inside xx.xxx.forEach

Tags: javascript

In this problem, it gives "TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", student.grades is an array in a .json file. ${average()} function works well, but the ${displayGrades()} gives error.

```
S_user.students.forEach(student => {
let htmlGrade = `<div id = "grades_detail"></div>`;
let htmlSegment2 =  `<div class="others">Average&nbsp;Grade:&nbsp;${average(student.grades)}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" onclick="${displayGrades(student.grades)}"> + </button></div>
<br />`
```

This part is outside of the forEach() and placed after it.

```
function displayGrades(lis){
    let html1 = '';
    const len = lis.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        html1 += 'Test' + parseFloat(i+1) + ':&nbsp;' + lis[i] + '%';
    }
    document.getElementById("grades_detail").innerHTML = html1;
}
```

Comment: the div [id=grades_detail] is not in DOM yet, when `displayGrades(student.grades)` is called

Comment: How do you add your HTML fragments to the DOM?

Comment: Also, ids have to be unique throughout the entire DOM. You create one element with `id = grades_detail` for every student. Therefore, the behaviour of `getElementById` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet

```
S_user.students.forEach((student,index) => {
      let htmlGrade = `<div id = "grades_detail_${index}"></div>
```

will create multiple div with same id `grades_detail`. `id` cannot be duplicate. Use `index` to give an unique id to the `div`

Secondly you are not attaching this div back to the dom. So in next function is not able too find the element in the dom

Comment: It is hard to name the id differently inside the forEach. Is there any method to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have the same is multiple times in your document, however for `getElementById` each ID has to be unique.

Possible solutions:

- append the number of the student in the list to the id
- use classes  to identify the elements (they don't have to be unique) and use `getElementsByClassName(...)[i]` and pass the student number i as a second parameter into the function
- pass the element to write the result into as a second parameter to your function